# how to match documents based on the date of execution of the query in mongoose

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

I'm writing a pipeline for a mongoose query which requires matching dates with the current date. I could use "new Date()" to obtain the new date but the pipeline is created once at server start. How can I write a statement which evaluates to the date of execution of the query? Maybe the date can be computed by mongodb itself?

Comment: You can use `$currentDate` operator. https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/

Comment: @CharchitKapoor thanks for the link. Actually I think that `$currentDate` cannot be used but I found in that page that the answer is to use the variable `$$NOW`

Comment: Cool. I didn't the exact query. So directed you there.

Comment: @CharchitKapoor if you write an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `$currentDate` operator, in your pipeline.

[Documentation link.](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/currentDate/)